# How do I use function field's 'glidefunction:concat' correctly in servicenow?

Tags: function, field, servicenow

I have created a new field in servicenow called `QI` (u_qi). I want to populate this field with three other fields in other words concatenate them.
My problem is, that the field is not showing up correctly. Instead of getting names, I get random chains of numbers and letters.

Here is the configuration:
[image]

And here is what I mean by random numbers and letter:

[image]

The only field showing up correctly is the `number` field.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't random numbers. The **number** field returns the CHGxxxxxx number and the other long strings are sys_id values that reference users. You need to call [getDisplayValue](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=madrid&id=r_GlideRecord-getDisplayValue) to get a meaningful value:

```
glidefunction:concat(number,',',requested_by.getDisplayValue(),',',assigned_to.getDisplayValue())
```

Comment: getDislpayValue does not work inside of Function Fields. Unlike other function fields, this is NOT a JS snippet (https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-platform-administration/page/build/platform-functions/concept/platform-support-functions.html)